# Avoid using static access to class '...' in method '...'

Tags: php, laravel

I've laravel app and decided to add `phpmd`.

Example code in `User` model

```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

   ...

   public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
     {   
         $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
     }
```

And `phpmd` shows error

```
Avoid using static access to class '\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash' in method 'setPasswordAttribute'.
```

How to deal with such errors?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you get this message when you make a static call to a method that's not defined as static. To avoid it, instantiate an instance of the class and then call `$obj->hash($value)`.

Comment: or use **= bcrypt($value)** instead.

Comment: Try `use Hash;` instead of  `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;`

Comment: From the docs: _"Static access causes inexchangable dependencies to other classes and leads to hard to test code. Avoid using static access at all costs and instead inject dependencies through the constructor. The only case when static access is acceptable is when used for factory methods."_

Comment: `Hash` is Laravel's Facade and the only way to use it: call static methods on Facade.

Comment: After reading the Laravel docs.. yeah, looks like you're just stuck with that message. phpmd seems rather unyielding in its stance and it doesn't know about the testability of Laravel's implementation.